# pytest: configure warnings by version

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

Using pytest `3.1`, I'm writing a library for python 2.7 and 3.4+ support. With python 3.4+, I'm getting various `ResourceWarning`s from underlying libraries when running tests, and I would to configure my `pytest.ini` file to ignore them. For Python 3, I can add add:

```
filterwarnings =
  ignore::ResourceWarning
```

However, I get an exception on Python 2.7, since that's an unrecognized warning. Is there a way to configure pytest to detect if a warning is supported or not? From my understanding of the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/features/warnings.html), this does not seem possible...but hoping someone might have a way.

Comment: You can add the controversial filter in your program after detecting the python version from `sys`, instead of adding it in the config file.

Comment: Ah, thanks, good idea. If you want to post an answer with example code, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm just a beginner with pytest myself, so I honestly wouldn't know where to stick that code. If you figure it out, go ahead and answer your own question though. I'm sure others will find it quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure this is a clean / acceptable answer, but following the idea from @Mad Physicist, I tried putting this in my `tests` module's `__init__.py` file:

```
import sys
import warnings

if sys.version_info >= (3,2):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ResourceWarning)
```

Unfortunately, that didn't do anything, I think because of this `pytest` [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2430). Basically `pytest 3.1` over-writes existing warning configurations and shows all warnings by default.

I've punted and gone with the `addopts = -p no:warnings` option to disable `pytest-warnings`, but hoping for a better way...